# Spotfire Where can I see how were the property controls set up?

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I am trying to duplicate a page from one dashboard to the other. In order to do so, I need to create the same property controls that are on the original page to my new page. Where can I see how were the property controls set up? 
I've tried several things: 
1. under Document Property - Properties, I can only see the first value for that property control but still don't know what are the rest. 
2. I am trying to dropbox-list the property control under text area, but when I click on the name of the control - the content does not show the corresponding setting of the control, which only let you to create/edit from the default. 
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated you are trying to see what the mappings are to a property control used in the text area, you have to "edit the text area" to see it.

In the text area, Right Click > Edit Text Area > Double Click the Property Control

This will bring up the configuration, specifically what the values are set to.